# Can one use the while(file >> ...) C++ idiom to read files in Cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'd like to use the C++ way of reading files in Cython.

I have a simple file reader that looks like this:

```
std::ifstream file(fileName);

while(file >> chromosome >> start >> end >> junk >> junk >> strand)
    { ... }
```

Can I do this in Cython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better options would be to use python parsing functionality (for example pandas' or numpy's) or, if first solution isn't flexible enough, to code the reader in pure C++ and then call the functionality from Cython.

However, also your approach is possible in Cython, but in order to make it work, one needs to jump through some hoops:

1. the whole `iostream` hierarchy isn't part of [the provided libcpp-wrappers](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/aaad38f78580193892ff4b4883bb28d5793c6b9e/Cython/Includes/libcpp), so one has to wrap it (and if one doesn't it quick&dirty that are a few lines).
2. Because `std::ifsteam` doesn't provide a default constructor, we cannot construct it as an object with automatic lifetime in Cython and need take care of memory management.
3. Another issue is wrapping of used-defined conversion. It is not very well described in the documentation (see this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59537827/5769463)), but only `operator bool()`][3](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/basic_ios/operator_bool/) is supported, so we need to use C++11 (otherwise it is `operator void*() const;`).

So here is a quick&dirty proof of concept:

```
%%cython  -+ -c=-std=c++11

cdef extern from "<fstream>" namespace "std" nogil:
    cdef cppclass ifstream:
        # constructor
        ifstream (const char* filename)

        # needed operator>> overloads:
        ifstream& operator>> (int& val)
        # others are
        # ifstream& operator>> (unsigned int& val)
        # ifstream& operator>> (long& val)
        # ...

        bint operator bool() # is needed, 
                             # so while(file) can be evaluated


def read_with_cpp(filename):
    cdef int a=0,b=0
    cdef ifstream* foo = new ifstream(filename)
    try:
        while (foo[0] >> a >> b):
            print(a, b)
    finally: # don't forget to call destructor!
        del foo
```

actually the return type of [`operator>>(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/basic_istream/operator%3E%3E/) is not `std::ifstream` but `std::basic_istream` - I'm just too lazy to wrap it as well.

And now:

```
>>> read_with_cpp(b"my_test_file.txt")
```

prints the content of the file to console.

---

However, as stated above, I would go for writing the parsing in pure C++ and consume it from Cython (e.g. by passing a functor, so the cpp-code can use Python functionality), here is a possible implementation:

```
%%cython  -+
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <fstream>
    void read_file(const char* file_name, void(*line_callback)(int, int)){
        std::ifstream file(file_name);
        int a,b;
        while(file>>a>>b){
           line_callback(a,b);
        }
    }
    """
    ctypedef void(*line_callback_type)(int, int)
    void read_file(const char* file_name, line_callback_type line_callback)

# use function pointer to get access to Python functionality in cpp-code: 
cdef void line_callback(int a, int b):
    print(a,b)

# expose functionality to pure Python:
def read_with_cpp2(filename):
    read_file(filename, line_callback)
```

and now calling `read_with_cpp2(b"my_test_file.txt")` leads to the same result as above.

Comment: Neat. I actually had an application where IO was the bottleneck and then using C++ to read the files was faster than Cython's `for line in f_handle; line.split()...`. Looking forward to benchmarking your functions. Also, never seen `cdef extern from *` in Cython. Do you have a short link to docs or an explanation?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat see https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#including-verbatim-c-code

Comment: @TheUnfunCat I don't think C++ IO is usually very quick. If you're worried about speed it might be worth trying C IO instead (which is a bit simpler to wrap since it doesn't involve classes or operator overloading)