# Cython: How user-defined conversion of C++-classes can be used?

Tags: python, c++, cython

Cython's [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#overloading-operators) seems to be silent about how [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) can be wrapped.

For example, while the following c++-code prints  `1` (i.e. `true`, [here live](https://ideone.com/FC9YW1)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct X{
    operator bool() const{ return true;}    
};

int main() {
    X x;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

its "equivalent" in Cython:

```py
%%cython  -+
cdef extern from *:
    """
    struct X {
        //implicit conversion
        operator bool() const { return true; }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass X:
        operator bool()  # ERROR HERE

def testit():
    cdef X x;
    print(x) # implicit cast, "should" print True
```

doesn't get cythonized with the following error message (in the line marked with `ERROR HERE`):

> 'operator' is not a type identifier

How user-defined conversion can be used from Cython and if not what are workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking only at the `bool` case:

1. I'm not convinced `print(x)` should convert it to bool anyway. `print(x)` looks for a conversion to a Python object (and OK, `bool` can be converted to a Python object, but it's somewhat indirect). Python itself uses the `__bool__` (`__nonzero__` in Python 2) only in fairly limited circumstances, like in an `if` statement, and Cython typically follows Python behaviour as a rule. Therefore I've changed the test-code to

   ```
   def testit():
       cdef X x
       if x:
           print("is True")
       else:
           print("if False")
   ```
2. `operator bool()` gives the error

   > 'operator' is not a type identifier

   I assumed it needed to start with the return type like every other C++ function (i.e. no special case for `operator`). This works (sort of... see next point...):

   ```
   bool operator bool()
   ```

   and this syntax is the one [tested for in Cython's testsuite](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/aaad38f78580193892ff4b4883bb28d5793c6b9e/tests/run/cpp_operators.pyx#L142).
3. However, you do need to do `from libcpp cimport bool` at the top of the file to get the C++ `bool` type.

If you look at the converted source for `if x:` it ends up as

```
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_v_x.operator bool();
if (__pyx_t_1) {
```

`operator bool` is called explicitly (which is pretty common for Cython), but is used in the correct place so Cython clearly understands what it's for. Similarly, if you do  `if x:` without defining the operator you get the error

> Object of type 'X' has no attribute 'operator bool'

again, suggesting this is a feature of Cython.

There's clearly a bit of a documentation failure here, and I wouldn't be 100% surprised if the syntax changed to match C++ a bit closer in the future, maybe.

---

For the more general case: [it looks like `bool` is the only type-conversion operator supported](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/5a8c984403ce73ac29f9e8b7c78ee5f0f4c608a3/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.py#L2834) at the moment, so you aren't able to define other operators.

Comment: You are probably right, to expect the conversion to a python object is too much.

Comment: C++ is a bit over-eager with automatic use of conversion operators and so it's often better to use `explicit` operators anyway to avoid that. It's probably sensible that Cython doesn't try to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This are only some additions to [DavidW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543270/5769463).

As already pointed out, only `operator bool` is supported by Cython - other user-defined conversions, like:

```py
cdef cppclass X:
    int operator int()
```

will result in an error message like

> Overloading operator 'int' not yet supported.

A possible workaround is not to wrap the user-defined conversion, but to use explicit cast whenever needed. For example:

```py
%%cython  -+ -a
cdef extern from *:
    """
    struct X {
        //implicit conversion
        operator int() const { return 42; }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass X:
        pass # leave operator int() out

def testit():
    cdef X x;
    print(<int>x)
```

which compiles and prints `42` once `testit` is called. Cython doesn't intervene with explicit cast here.

Ironically, the above workaround would not work for `operator bool()`:

```py
%%cython  -+ -a
cdef extern from *:
    """
    struct X {
        //implicit conversion
        operator bool() const { return true; }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass X:
        pass # leave operator bool() out

def testit():
    cdef X x;
    if <bint>x:
       print(True)
    else:
       print(False)
```

leads to error message:

> Object of type 'X' has no attribute 'operator bool'

Obviously, this check is a part of the `operator bool()`-support package..

One could however use cast to `int` instead of cast to `bool/bint` to achieve the goal:

```py
...
if <int>x:
...
```

However, should wrapping the `operator bool()` should be prefered.

---

In a nutshell:

1. use `bint operator bool()` to wrap C++'s `operator bool()`
2. don't wrap and use explicit cast for other operators.