# Cython importing C++ operators: "Overloading operator '+=' not yet supported."

Tags: cython

I'm trying to use the MPFR C++ library, because I'd like to have simple operators (e.g. "+=" or even just "+") for the MPFR numbers.

My simple example is the following

```
cdef extern from "mpreal.h" namespace "mpfr":
    cdef cppclass mpreal:
        mpreal() except +
        mpreal(const double) except +
        mpreal& operator+=(const mpreal& v) except +
```

However, Cython complains

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef extern from "mpreal.h" namespace "mpfr":
    cdef cppclass mpreal:
        mpreal() except +
        mpreal(const double) except +
        mpreal& operator+=(const mpreal& v) except +
                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test_000.pyx:6:26: Overloading operator '+=' not yet supported.
```

Some operators are mentioned on https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html to have slightly different syntax, but the "+=" operator isn't mentioned anywhere on the internet, and fairly simple and common at the same time, so I'm confused.

My question is fairly stupid: Have I made a mistake somewhere, or is the error message correct in the sense that the "+=" operator is just not yet supported by Cython? Other operators like "=" (seem to) work.

**EDIT:** User ead pointed out something in the src of Cython (https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/5a8c984403ce73ac29f9e8b7c78ee5f0f4c608a3/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.py#L2834) which I understand as "+=" is just not supported.

But looking at https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/5a8c984403ce73ac29f9e8b7c78ee5f0f4c608a3/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.py#L2909 I'm wondering if this could be easily extended and the code comments actually suggest that? Maybe I can figure it out myself and make a contribution, but if anyone knows what's going on I would be happy to hear about it.

```
        elif s.sy == '=':
            op += s.sy    # +=, -=, ...
            s.next()
        if op not in supported_overloaded_operators:
            s.error("Overloading operator '%s' not yet supported." % op,
                    fatal=False)
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**
The discussion is on https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3696 as well, and as it looks right now ead's suggestion will be added/fixed in Cython.

Comment: FYI: list of supported operators: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/5a8c984403ce73ac29f9e8b7c78ee5f0f4c608a3/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.py#L2834

Comment: @ead: That's actually a good enough answer for me (i.e. I will accept it if you post it). So "+=" is just not supported as of now. Too bad.

Comment: Maybe it is only forgotten and adding to the list would work out of the box...

Comment: @ead: I actually tried that an hour before your comment. No luck. I still don't really understand what's happening in Cython's Parsing.py (and after that in Nodes.py), so for now it's out of my skillset to make working changes. Maybe I will figure it out later. But I will actually post this as an issue in Cython's github.

Comment: FYI: workaround for conversion operators: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59537827/5769463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks as if operator `+=` was just forgotten: `+=` (and also `-=`, `*=`, `/=`) are no different than the normal assignment operator `=`.

When I change [this line in Cython-code](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/5a8c984403ce73ac29f9e8b7c78ee5f0f4c608a3/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.py#L2834), which enumerates supported operators, to

```
supported_overloaded_operators = cython.declare(set, set([
    '+', '-', '*', '/', '%',
    '++', '--', '~', '|', '&', '^', '<<', '>>', ',',
    '==', '!=', '>=', '>', '<=', '<',
    '[]', '()', '!', '=',
    'bool', '+=',            #`+=` added!
]))
```

I can successfully build and use the following minimalistic reproducer:

```
%%cython -+ -c=-std=c++11

cdef extern from *:
    """
    struct A{
    int x=42;
    A& operator+=(const A&o){
        x+=o.x;
      }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass A:
        int x
        A& operator+=(const A& v)
        
def doit():
    cdef A a;
    a+=a;
    print(a.x)
```

And now:

```
doit()  # prints 84
```

does the job.

Comment: Damn, you're right. My mistake was somewhere else. I mixed pointers and actual variables... I had to write "aa[0]+=bb[0]" instead of aa+=bb. At least I have a small excuse that with Cython/C/C++ the different semantics get a little bit messy.